# Regex to match all words, inclusive of punctuation and unicode characters. No white space

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, match, whitespace

I'm currently using this: `/([A-z0-9'<>,-.()–:'/]+)/g` to wrap all the words in a `<p>` tag with `<span>` tags. This is working well, except I have to define any punctuation that is added and not already defined.

Is there a better regex pattern that I can use to match ***ALL*** characters and punctuation (inclusive of unicode characters), that breaks on white space?

Examples:

`"Hi, hello there!" => <span>Hi,</span> <span>hello</span> <span>there!</span>`

as well as:

`"俺の　名前　は　tr3online　です。" => <span>俺の</span> <span>名前</span> <span>は</span> <span>tr3online</span> <span>です。</span>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use negated character class to match anything apart from `\s`:

```
/([^\s]+)/g
```

or `\S` for matching non-whitespace characters. This is same as `[^\s]`

```
/(\S+)/g
```